# Work with two separate Facebook pages with IFTTT

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

I have two Facebook pages, say Page A and Page B. I have two blogs as well. I have linked the first blog to Page A, but now I wanna link the 2nd blog to Page B, but it keeps taking me back to Page A. Instead of the 2nd blog linking to page B, it links to Page A. How can I rectify this issue on IFTTT?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one Facebook page connection on your IFTTT account. As you may have guessed -- and I have tried it myself -- you cannot associate your same Facebook account to another IFTTT account to get around the limitation of only one page connection.

This is a *huge* limitation that I highly recommend you join me in bringing this issue up with their support group.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IFTTT only lets you configure one Facebook page with the Facebook Pages channel for your account.

For what you want to do, you'd need to create a new IFTTT account. (Assuming, of course, that IFTTT doesn't prevent multiple accounts from linking to the same Facebook account.)

Otherwise, you'll need to find a different way to do what you want. [Zapier](https://zapier.com) may be of use.